# Strange concrete pad ringed with bricks in basement

Tags: concrete, basement, foundation

I'm developing a Victorian flat (UK) the moment and there's a room that I wanted to clear out but there appears to be a load-bearing support beam with a concrete support pad at the base...I'm wondering at the bricks surrounding the concrete pad though.  Are they decorative or were they used simply to create the seating for the wet concrete?  You can see the support column and the bricks running along the concrete at the base.

- Can I take the bricks out?
- Is there a space saving structural alternative to the concrete pad at the base of the column?

[image: Pad with bricks]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to remove the `tinyurl.com` links and use Stack Exchange's own hosting solution for your images. By clicking the "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box, you can either upload an image from your computer or past a URL to the `*.jpg` or `*.png` and the site will embed the image for you. Posting a `tinyurl.com` link can seem suspicious to the more paranoid (since SE will host it), and makes people work harder than necessary to answer your question.

Comment: I prefer "wisely cautious". "Paranoid" implies that there's no risk. Links removed to save others from wasting time.

Comment: Right now you don't even know whether that concrete pad & brick ring have anything to do with the support post (column) at all.  Quite possibly the brick stack continues down to the floor or below.  Other than bashing away at the concrete, there may be no way to  determine this.  The pad might have been put in for some unrelated reason.

Comment: For that matter, I would get a licensed structural engineer in to have a look.  Maybe the entire column is unnecessary,  or maybe there's an internal pipe or chimney doing something completely different.

Comment: maybe it's a sealed entrance into the dungeon ... lol